# Use a sub domain like app.mysite.com hosting in Google Cloud DNS in Firebase as domain

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-hosting, google-cloud-dns

This process is very confusing. Since Firebase has a warning now said CNAME record is not support. What I used to do is to set up a CNAME in Google Cloud DNS as app.mysite.com and the Canonical name point to the Firebase domain eg. myapp-9afa9.firebaseapp.com. (the mysite.com is pointing to somewhere else with A record - hosting my static website in Surge.sh. So I can not change my A record in Google Cloud DNS). Then in Firebase, I just connect domain and point to app.mysite.com. And then I add the TXT file in Google Cloud DNS. Firebase, for now, can find the domain and connect. But it show me a next screen says I need to change the A record to the 2 records that provided. And warning says CNAME record is no longer support... They are ALL GOOGLE PRODUCTS!! Why can't I use subdomain as my app domain in Firebase anymore? What is the correct workflow to use subdomain for Firebase?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can definitely use A records on subdomains. Here's an example of the add dialog on Cloud DNS:

[image]

What you can't do is have a CNAME and A records on the *same* subdomain at the *same* time. If you already have a CNAME for `app.mysite.com` you'll need to remove it before adding A records.

In addition, you can actually still use a CNAME to point to Firebase Hosting if you wish. We stopped recommending it during domain setup because CNAMEs only work on subdomains, not apex/registered domains and we found it to be too confusing to try to describe the differences.

Comment: Oh yes! That is exactly the answer I am looking for. Great. I think I will continue to use CNAME for subdomain as it works best. So just to clarify, I can ignore the last screen of Firebase suggestion re the A domain. And my above workflow will work? (it does work. I just want to make sure you won't disable support in the future)

Comment: Yes, a CNAME will continue to be supported for the foreseeable future.